# Customize expand/collapse button in NavBarGroup in Devexpress

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, devexpress

I have a NavBarControl which contains collection of NavBarGroups.
NavBarGroup have a header and container control. NavBarGroups can be collapsed/expanded.
The button to expand/collapse is on right side. By default it looks like double up/down arrow. I want to customize this button to change its look and feel to indicate collapsed/expanded state.

(using Devexpress in Windows Forms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, the self-help and online support at DevExpress is exceptionally thorough, and they will answer questions like this for paid subscribers within 24 hours, usually with a code sample.

In this case there are two ways to achieve your goal (assuming you're on a relatively recent version of DevExpress) as described [here](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q447259).

The "right way" to do what you want is to make a custom skin with your own icons; you can use their skin editor to open your current skin, make changes, and save it. Nearly every aspect of the look & feel of their controls is skinned and you can make pretty significant changes to them.

Deploying custom skins isn't all that complex but it might be a bit overkill for the effect you're trying to achieve. The other option is to custom draw the group caption. There's a sample attached to that post that is a working example of doing so, but you basically implement the [CustomDrawGroupCaption](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraNavBarNavBarControl_CustomDrawGroupCaptiontopic) event and do your own painting, including whatever icons you want based on the group's state.

Comment: Thanks, http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q447259 is what I required.